# How to modify modules in Python with pycharm

Tags: python, module, pycharm

I downloaded a python module...lets say `paramiko` and I would like modify the package and be able to import the new code from the package i.e.

```
from paramiko.new_module import *
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I want to be able to test code changes before I try to merge it with the other code in a seamless way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clone the repository of [`paramiko`](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko) and start modifying the code.

Then install the package with pip in edit-mode:

```
cd /to/your/repo
pip install -e .
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for :)